# Mustache : how to keep And condition in mustache

Tags: php, mustache, mustache.php

Below is how i am using with Mustache.If source is there i am showing `{{#flag_sour}}` data, if destination is there i am showing `{{#flag_dest}}` data.

```
{{#onwardfl}}                            
{{#flag_sour}}                           
<div class="col-xs-12 flightbooking noleftpadding">
<div class="col-xs-12">
<p  style="color:#165391;">  this is not a direct flight </p>
</div>

</div>
{{/flag_sour}}
{{#flag_dest}}                           
<div class="col-xs-12 flightbooking noleftpadding">
<div class="col-xs-12">
<p style="color:#165391;">  this is not a direct flight </p>
</div>

</div>
{{/flag_dest}}
{{/onwardfl}}
```

if `{{#flag_sour}}` and `{{#flag_dest}}` are both there i want to show only one message this is not a direct flight. How can i do this with mustache.

Comment: @unixarmy gave the correct answer, it is not possible. I guess the easiest way would to achieve the desired functionality would be to create new `flag_direct` value in the data (thus not computed by Mustache)

Answer (score 1):

[Mustache](https://mustache.github.io/) is "logic-less" template engine, so if you are using [Model-view-controller architecture](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Model%E2%80%93view%E2%80%93controller), it would be better to solve your problem in your controller.

That's the idea of logicless templating.